# Is it possible to disable Bitlocker for Windows 10 Safe mode?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption, safe-mode

Every time I'm in the process of booting into Windows 10 Safe Mode, it asks for the Bitlocker recovery key. Is there some way to either permanently or temporary disable Bitlocker for Safe Mode/diagnostic purposes?

Comment: No. That would defeat the whole purpose of Bitlocker, which is to secure the data on the disk.

Comment: Your disk is encrypted regardless if you boot normally or if you boot into Safe Mode.  In your current state BitLocker requires the Recovery Key.  If you were to wipe the TPM keys you would still require the recovery key.  If you don't have the recovery key data recovery is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible.

Bitlocker does harddrive encryption. After you enable it, the boot process will be
changed to POST, decryption, then OS load.

So Safe mode or normal mode boot follows BitLocker enabling.
Or in other words, BitLocker does not know nor cares about the Windows boot mode.